# basedir must be absolute: ?/.ivy2/local

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, ivy, jupyterhub

I'm writing here in a full desperation state...

I have 2 users:

- 1 local user, created in Linux. Works 100% fine, word count works perfectly. Kerberized Cluster. Valid ticket.
- 1 Active Directory user, can login, but pyspark instruction (same word count) fails. Same kdc ticket as the one above.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: basedir
>   must be absolute: ?/.ivy2/local
>       at org.apache.ivy.util.Checks.checkAbsolute(Checks.java:48)
>       at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.file.FileRepository.setBaseDir(FileRepository.java:135)
>       at org.apache.ivy.plugins.repository.file.FileRepository.(FileRepository.java:44)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitUtils$.createRepoResolvers(SparkSubmit.scala:943)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitUtils$.buildIvySettings(SparkSubmit.scala:1035)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:295)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:295)
>       at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:294)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:153)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

The Code I'm running. Super simple.

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("yarn")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

It ends in error in the last instruction with the above error (see exception).

`?/.ivy2/local` -> This is the problem but I have no idea what's going on :(.

With the Linux user it works perfectly... but with the AD user that doesn't exists in the local system, but has /home/userFolder ... I have this problem :(

Please help... I've reach the point of insanity... I've googled every corner of the internet but I haven't found any solution to this problem/mistake :( stackoverflow is my last resort heeeeeeeeeelp

Comment: Same problem here, but in my case it's because I'm using openshift, which creates a unique user ID for each deployment.  It looks like ivy can't retrieve the user's particulars via system calls.

Comment: @CarlF.: do you have solved your issue with OpenShift? We have the same problem.

Comment: @KeyMaker00 yes.  It's a bit of a kludge but the solution is to make the /etc/passwd file in your docker image writable by group root and then add an entry for the randomly assigned user when the container starts. This guide is helpful. https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/creating_images/guidelines.html#openshift-specific-guidelines

Answer (score 17):

**Context**

Ivy needs a directory called `.ivy2`, usually located in the home directory. You can also configure where `.ivy2` should be by giving a configuration property when Spark starts, or when you execute `spark-submit`.

**Where the problem comes from**

In [IvySettings.java](https://github.com/apache/ant-ivy/blob/2.2.0/src/java/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/IvySettings.java) (line 796 for the version 2.2.0 of ant-ivy) there is this line:

```
if (getVariable("ivy.home") != null) {
   setDefaultIvyUserDir(Checks.checkAbsolute(getVariable("ivy.home"), "ivy.home"));
   Message.verbose("using ivy.default.ivy.user.dir variable for default ivy user dir: " + defaultUserDir);
} else {
   setDefaultIvyUserDir(new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".ivy2"));
   Message.verbose("no default ivy user dir defined: set to " + defaultUserDir);
}
```

As you can see, if `ivy.home` is not set, and `user.home` is also not set, then you will get the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: basedir must be absolute: ?/.ivy2/local

**Solution 1 (spark-shell or spark-submit)**

As [Rocke Yang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2015518/rockie-yang) has mentioned, you can start spark-shell or spark-submit by setting the configuration property spark.jars.ivy. Example:

```
spark-shell --conf spark.jars.ivy=/tmp/.ivy
```

**Solution 2 (spark-launcher or yarn-client)**

A second solution would be to set the configuration property when calling the submit method programmatically:

```
sparkLauncher.setSparkHome("/path/to/SPARK_HOME")
  .setAppResource("/path/to/jar/to/be/executed")
  .setMainClass("MainClassName")
  .setMaster("MasterType like yarn or local")
  .setDeployMode("set deploy mode like cluster")
  .setConf("spark.executor.cores","2")
  .setConf("spark.jars.ivy","/tmp/.ivy")
```

**Ticket opened**

There is a [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19630) opened by Spark-Community

Answer (score 5):

I have met similar issue with this.

SparkSubmit will looking for ivy home directly. If not found it will report an error. And the name changed slightly on the way.

```
class SparkSubmitArguments {
    ivyRepoPath = sparkProperties.get("spark.jars.ivy").orNull
}
```

We can pass the ivy.home directory by like this

```
spark-shell --conf spark.jars.ivy=/tmp/.ivy
```