# Spark + Zeppelin on Kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I try to follow this doc: https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.9.0-SNAPSHOT/quickstart/kubernetes.html

Zeppelin installation - OK

Spark Image - OK

When i try to run:

```
%spark.conf
spark.executor.instances 3

%spark
sc.parallelize(1 to 100).count
```

First i have this error: [Spark on kubernetes with zeppelin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61211932/spark-on-kubernetes-with-zeppelin) (and i use this issue to solve it)

and then i try to run again and i have this error:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/zeppelin/interpreter/spark/spark-interpreter-0.9.0-preview1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/spark/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
 WARN [2020-05-15 21:00:00,404] ({main} NativeCodeLoader.java[<clinit>]:62) - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: failure to login
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:822)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:774)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:647)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2422)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2422)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2422)
    at org.apache.spark.SecurityManager.<init>(SecurityManager.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.secMgr$lzycompute$1(SparkSubmit.scala:348)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$secMgr$1(SparkSubmit.scala:348)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$7.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:356)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$7.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:356)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:774)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.lang.NullPointerException: invalid null input: name
    at com.sun.security.auth.UnixPrincipal.<init>(UnixPrincipal.java:71)
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.UnixLoginModule.login(UnixLoginModule.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:797)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:774)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:647)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2422)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2422)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2422)
    at org.apache.spark.SecurityManager.<init>(SecurityManager.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.secMgr$lzycompute$1(SparkSubmit.scala:348)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$secMgr$1(SparkSubmit.scala:348)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$7.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:356)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$7.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:356)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:774)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:920)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:929)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:856)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:797)
    ... 20 more
```

Anyone can help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `SPARK_USER=zeppelin` in the interpreter configuration, in the same place you specified the `SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS`

Comment: Hello, after a set more options on SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS, the error comes back.

Before SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS=--conf spark.jars.ivy=/tmp/.ivy (Works Fine)

After SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS=--conf spark.jars.ivy=/tmp/.ivy --repositories https://packages.confluent.io/maven/ --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.4,org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.4,org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.4,za.co.absa:abris_2.11:3.1.2 (ther error about user comes back)

Anyone can help me?